# Android stetho Google Developer tools resources truncated

Tags: android, google-developer-tools, google-developers-console, stetho

Using Stetho and Stetho Realm.

```
Stetho.initialize(
                Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                        .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                        .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build())
                        .build());
```

I am able to see Realm DB content with Google Developer Console, but the maximum index is 249, all values after that are truncated -

[image]

How can I force it to show all the values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is the limit inside Stetho. In the class

`com.facebook.stetho.inspector.protocol.module.Database`

https://github.com/facebook/stetho/blob/36aa5bd356d9cf5893b9424b06a83dda9ec5e44f/stetho/src/main/java/com/facebook/stetho/inspector/protocol/module/Database.java

There is this info -

```
  /**
   * The protocol doesn't offer an efficient means of pagination or anything like that so
   * we'll just cap the result list to some arbitrarily large number that I think folks will
   * actually need in practice.
   * <p>
   * Note that when this limit is exceeded, a dummy row will be introduced that indicates
   * truncation occurred.
   */
  private static final int MAX_EXECUTE_RESULTS = 250;
```

And in case for Realm Stetho, it is possible to change the limit in this way-

```
Stetho.initialize(
                Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                        .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                        .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this)
                                .withFolder(getCacheDir())
                                .withMetaTables()
                                .withDescendingOrder()
                                .withLimit(100000)
                                .build())
                        .build());
```